# Excel VBA Delete Row and Suppress Prompt

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with several sheets in it. One sheet is a template that allows users to fill in data and then when they click on a "Generate" cell it creates a new sheet within the workbook with all the information. It actually copies an invisible worksheet with code in it and that copied worksheet is renamed by what the user specified in the initial template.

I then have another sheet called "Open". Within column A, starting at Row 3 the new sheet name is entered in the first blank cell, and then it auto-sorts. The user can then click on the sheet name within the Open sheet and it will jump to that sheet.

On the sheets that are generated each sheet has a "Delete" cell. When the user clicks on it, it will prompt the user if they are sure they want to delete the sheet. If they select no then nothing happens, but if they select yes it will delete the sheet and also remove the sheet name from the list on the "Open" sheet.  If the user selects resolved from a dropdown it will also work the same as clicking the delete button, but it doesn't prompt the user if they are sure they want to delete, it just deletes it.

That is a very brief breakdown of what this does and all of this code works great.

What I am trying to do is add additional information to the "Open" sheet, filling in columns B and C as well. The Open sheet is automatically populated and updated as sheets are created, updated, and resolved. This is not a problem and have it working. The problem is trying to write code that will delete the entire row within the Open sheet and not prompt the user about too many cells being changed (explanation on this prompt is below).

In the "Open" sheet I have code that prevents users from changing more than one cell at a time. If multiple cells are deleted, it allows for this and no message is displayed. If more than 1 cell is populated, it will alert the user and undo the changes. The code for this is below and does work.

**Open Sheet Code**

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    vData = Target.Formula
    For Each vClear In vData
        If vClear <> "" Then 'If data is only deleted then more than one cell can be changed.
            MsgBox "Change only one cell at a time", , "Too Many Changes!"
                Application.Undo
                Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

In the new sheets that get generated I have this code for when the user wants to delete the sheet.

**Generated Sheet Code**

```
If Target.Address = rDelete.Address Then
    sSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    If sSheetName <> "Template2" Then
        sYesNo = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete outage " & sSheetName & "?", vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Delete Outage " & sSheetName)
        If sYesNo = 6 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Suppresses the confirmation when deleting a worksheet
            'Removes the site name when the outage is deleted from the Open sheet
            Do Until ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open").Cells(iOpen, 1).Value2 = "" Or ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open").Cells(iOpen, 1).Value2 = sSheetName
                iOpen = iOpen + 1
            Loop
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open").Cells(iOpen, 1).Value2 = ""
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sSheetName).Delete
            Worksheets("Template").Activate
            Exit Sub
        Else
            rDelete.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    End If
End If
```

All of that code works great. However since before I was only adding to column A on the "Open" sheet, I only needed to clear that one cell containing the sheet name on the Open sheet, which is what this code does within the generated sheets.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open").Cells(iOpen, 1).Value2 = ""
```

I now need to change that line to this instead.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Open").Rows(iOpen).EntireRow.Delete
```

That code does work, but the problem is the user is then alerted with the message saying "Too Many Changes" due to the code that is on the Open sheet. I need to somehow suppress that message when the entire row is being deleted.

I tried this code within the Open sheet, but it doesn't exactly work.

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    vData = Target.Formula
    For Each vClear In vData
        If Selection.Rows(1).Cells.Count <> Columns.Count Then 'If entire row is deleted it allows it, like for a resolved outage or deleting the outage
            If vClear <> "" Then 'If data is only deleted then more than one cell can be changed.
                MsgBox "Change only one cell at a time", , "Too Many Changes!"
                Application.Undo
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
```

The difference between this code and the original one for the open sheet is I added an If and End If Line. The line that was added is:

```
If Selection.Rows(1).Cells.Count <> Columns.Count Then
```

I said it doesn't exactly work because if I am on the Open sheet itself, select a row, right click and select delete, this does work and the prompt is not received saying too many changes. However when I actually click on the "Delete" cell within one of the generated sheets I still receive the prompt saying:

> Too Many Changes

But it does delete the row anyway. Deleting the row is what I want, but I don't want the prompt saying too many changes.

Sorry for the long explanation, but I thought it was needed to understand what is going on.

Comment: Maybe this will help. From Object Browser. `Property DisplayAlerts As Boolean Member of Excel.Application `. And pressing F1 gets `The default value is True. Set this property to False if you don’t want to be disturbed by prompts and alert messages while a macro is running; any time a message requires a response, Microsoft Excel chooses the default response.

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I should just have used this instead:

```
If Selection.Rows.Count <> 1 Then
```

instead of what I was trying to use, which was:

```
If Selection.Rows(1).Cells.Count <> Columns.Count Then
```

This appears to be working well. I am being prompted when I should and am not being prompted when I shouldn't be.